# rename all file names in a directory

Tags: rename

I have say 100 files all with the same text I want to replace with something else. For example, I have the file names:

```
blahtest
blah-yes
blahokay
blahcool
```

I want to replace `blah` with `mytext`. Is there any way to do that? All files are different too, not the same file type.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Please clarify your question. We couldn't possibly give answers to every operating system there is. Once edited it can be reopened—simply drop a comment or flag the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few batch-renaming utilities online like this one:
[Bulk Rename](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)

Windows Explorer can do it if you're okay with every file having the same name with a number appended to the end. You can just highlight them all, press F2, type the new name, and press enter.

Comment: You're assuming one particular answer to grawity's question.

Comment: @JdeBP Because I provided only one batch-renaming utility?

Comment: Because you only addressed one operating system.